# Validate crypted file with public key

Tags: public-key-encryption, gnupg

I have a server in a hosting with gnupg module and all works fine. The user can crypt messages with my public key (this process should do in a local, not in the server) and upload this messages in my server. I want validate that the "file" was encrypted with my public key

The user type something like that and them upload the file into my server.

```
gpg --encrypt --recipient 12345678 file.txt
```

I dont want share my private key in this server, so i cant validate if i will can decrypt. My question is, can i validate what file was crypted with my own public key??

Sorry by my english

Answer (score 0):

use gpg --decrypt  but don't give your private key, gpg will tell you all the keys that it is encrypted with:

```
wwalker@hatter:~$ gpg --decrypt foo.asc

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Wayne Walker (Ruby Hacker) <wwalker@bybent.com>"
4096-bit ELG-E key, ID 39D0C3D7, created 2007-12-31 (main key ID A62B624A)

gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: encrypted with 1024-bit ELG-E key, ID 70DAE878, created 2015-10-15
      "Puppet Vault (Used for targeted secrets exchanges) <puppet@pumhost2.lbl.gov>"
gpg: encrypted with 1024-bit ELG-E key, ID 9426026B, created 2015-10-15
      "Puppet Vault (Used for targeted secrets exchanges) <puppet@jenkins.lbl.gov>"
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit ELG-E key, ID 39D0C3D7, created 2007-12-31
      "Wayne Walker (Ruby Hacker) <wwalker@bybent.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: bad passphrase
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
```

If you are already using gpg-agent and your key is already in the agent:

```
(unset GPG_AGENT_INFO; gpg --decrypt foo.asc)
```